# Unable to Send PDF attachment through Mule HTTPEndPoint

Tags: pdf, mule, attachment

I have a requirement wherein i will submit data from an html form to Mule flow and Mule should return me an PDF file. I have created a following flow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <flow name="SampleMuleFlow1" doc:name="SampleMuleFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/pdf"
            mimeType="application/pdf">
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <custom-transformer returnClass="org.mule.api.MuleMessage"
            mimeType="application/pdf"
            class="com.tcs.pdfgen.GenerateGFEService_GenerateGFEServiceImplPort_Client"
            doc:name="Java" />

    </flow>
</mule>

I attach the PDF file through the api   message.addOutboundAttachment().Please check the Custom Tranformer file i have written.

package com.tcs.pdfgen;

/**
 * Please modify this class to meet your needs
 * This class is not complete
 */
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.cxf.attachment.LazyDataSource;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;



    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
            throws TransformerException {
        try {
            GenerateGFEService_GenerateGFEServiceImplPort_Client client = new GenerateGFEService_GenerateGFEServiceImplPort_Client();

/*client.genGFE(message, "GeneratedSamplePDF.pdf") method return a byte array of the PDF file.*/

            message.addOutboundAttachment("GFEFile",
                    client.genGFE(message, "GeneratedSamplePDF.pdf"),
                    "application/pdf");

            System.out.println("Attachment Names>>>>"
                    + message.getOutboundAttachmentNames());

            System.out.println("ApplicationHome settings>>>"
                    + message.getOutboundProperty("ApplicationHome"));

            return message;
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            System.out.println("exception 1111");
            System.out.println("Exception Message>>>>>>" + ioe.getMessage());
            throw new TransformerException(this, ioe);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("exception?>>>" + t.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {

            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

But on the browser , i get an error the PDF not starting with "%PDF".I believe the PDF attachment is not sent through the HTTP Response Object.Please let me know, If i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Set the PDF content input stream as the message payload not as an attachment: that way Mule will stream it back to the browser.